# How can I tell if a file is on a remote filesystem with Perl?

Tags: perl, shell, filesystems, nfs

Is there a quick-and-dirty way to tell programmatically, in shell script or in Perl, whether a path is located on a remote filesystem (nfs or the like) or a local one? Or is the only way to do this to parse /etc/fstab and check the filesystem type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`stat -f -c %T <filename>` should do what you want.  You might also want `-l`

Comment: Again, not portable to Solaris (though I have the command on the machine, it is not standard issue).

Answer (score 2):

You can use "df -T" to get the filesystem type for the directory, or use the -t option to limit reporting to specific types (like nfs) and if it comes back with "no file systems processed", then it's not one of the ones you're looking for.

```
df -T $dir | tail -1 | awk '{print $2;}'
```

Comment: Not portable - 'df -T' does not work on Solaris, for instance.

Comment: If all network filesystems use host:path semantics for the device name, then I suppose you can check for : in the device name or something to that effect then.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `df` on a directory to get info only of the device it resides in, e.g. for the current directory:

```
df .
```

Then, you can just parse the output, e.g.

```
df . | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

to get the device name.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following on solaris7,8,9 & 10 and it seems to be reliable

```
/bin/df -g <filename> | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Should give you have the fs type rather than trying to match for a "host:path" in your mount point.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, the device number is negative for NFS files. Thus,

```
print "remote" if (stat($filename))[0] < 0
```