# How do I determine if a directory is a mounted NFS mount point in shellscript

Tags: bash, unix, shell, nfs

I want to write a sh/bash script that can determine whether a particular directory is a mount point for an NFS filesystem.

eg something like

```
$ mkdir localdir
$ mkdir remotedir
$ mount host:/share ./remotedir
$ classify_dirs.sh
 -->  localdir is local
 -->  remotedir is an NFS mount point
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This question is effectively a dup of  [how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-on-a-remote-filesystem-with-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296455/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-on-a-remote-filesystem-with-perl)

The short answer is to use the `stat` command

eg

```
$ stat -f -L -c %T localdir
ext2/ext3
$ stat -f -L -c %T remotedir
nfs
```

Then a directory is an NFS mount point if its type is 'nfs' and its parent directory isn't.

Comment: When I run this, I get the error `illegal option -- c`. Has stat changed substantially since this answer was written?

Comment: @DanI would guess its a Mac vs Linux delta