# How to tell (in sh) whether a directory is mounted over NFS

Tags: shell, nfs

df -t nfs $directory

returns two lines of output if the directory is NFS-mounted and one line if it isn't.

Some versions of df give exit status 1 if it wasn't NFS-mounted, but GNU coreutils 5.3.0 doesn't ...

```
if [ `df -t nfs . | wc -l` = 2 ];
```

feels inelegant and colleagues say that it doesn't check sufficiently for errors.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've tried out a few options, but yours still seems more elegant to me. Did you colleagues mention the errors that would elude this method? +1 for a nice attempt.

Comment: OK, I found one problem. If the first output column is exceedingly long (e.g. `nfs_server:/long/mount/point`), then `df` would split the output across two lines and you end up with `wc -l = 3`. Easily solved by changing your solution to `if [ .... -gt 1 ]`.

Comment: @ShawnChin: If you apply the `--portability` / `-P` option it won't wrap long lines. Perfect for machine processing. (Tested with `df (GNU coreutils) 7.4`)

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate question [How do I determine if a directory is an NFS mount point in shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460047/how-do-i-determine-if-a-directory-is-an-nfs-mount-point-in-shellscript). Short answer, use the `stat` command.

Comment: +1 Well spotted. From the linked answer, equivalent solution would be `if [ $(stat -f -L -c %T .) == "nfs" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check mtab it keeps a record of all mounted filesystems in a flatfile, if you use strace and look that is all df does anyway. I suppose you could also use /proc/mounts if your running this in Linux.

Comment: Using to `/etc/mtab` would require a lot more parsing/processing. Would also fail if target directory includes a sym link to a mount point.