# Search filesystem via perl script while ignoring remote mounts

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

I've written a perl script that is designed to search a server for world writable files. After some testing, though, I've found that I made a mistake in the logic. Specifically, I've told it to not search `/`. My initial thought behind this was that I was looking for locally mounted volumes while avoiding those of a remote variety (`CIFS`, `NFS`, what-have-you).

What I failed to take into consideration is that not every directory has a unique volume. As a result, by excluding `/` in my scan, I've missed several directories that should be included. Now I need to rework the script to include those while still excluding remote volumes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Directives which establish our execution environment
use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

# Variables used throughout the script
my $DIR = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $MTAB = "/etc/mtab";
my $PERMFILE = "world_writable_w_files.txt";
my $TMPFILE = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $EXCLUDE = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

# Create the filehandle for the /etc/mtab file
open MT, "<${MTAB}" or die "Cannot open ${MTAB}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints that are not "/"
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]) unless ($_ =~ /root/);
  }
}

close MT;

# Read in the list of excluded files
my $regex = do {
  open EXCLD, "<${EXCLUDE}" or die "Cannot open ${EXCLUDE}, $!\n";
  my @ignore = <EXCLD>;
  chomp @ignore;
  local $" = '|';
  qr/@ignore/;
};

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir "${DIR}" or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${DIR}, $!" unless (-d "${DIR}");

# Create the filehandle for writing the findings
open WWFILE, ">${DIR}${TMPFILE}" or die "Cannot open ${DIR}${TMPFILE}, $!";

foreach (@mounts) {
  # The anonymous subroutine which is executed by File::Find
  find sub {
    return unless -f; # Is it a regular file...

    # ...and world writable.
    return unless (((stat)[2] & S_IWUSR) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWGRP) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWOTH));

    # Add the file to the list of found world writable files unless it is
    # in the list if exclusions
    print WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n" unless ($File::Find::name =~ $regex);

  }, $_;
}

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${TMPFILE} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${DIR}${TMPFILE}") {
  unlink "${DIR}${TMPFILE}";

} else {
  rename("${DIR}${TMPFILE}","${DIR}${PERMFILE}") or die "Cannot rename file ${DIR}${TMPFILE}, $!";

}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to approach this now. I know I can obtain the necessary information using `stat -f -c %T` but I don't see a similar option for perl's built-in `stat` (unless I'm misinterpreting the descriptions for output fields; perhaps it is found in one of the `S_` variables?).

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction. I'd really rather not drop to a shell command to obtain this information.

EDIT: I've found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296655/1602022), but it seems to be not entirely helpful. When I test the built-in `stat` against a `CIFS` mount I get `18`. Perhaps what I need is a comprehensive list of values that could be returned for remote files to compare against?

EDIT2: This is the script in its new form which meets the requirements:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Directives which establish our execution environment
use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

# Variables used throughout the script
my $DIR = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $MTAB = "/etc/mtab";
my $PERMFILE = "world_writable_w_files.txt";
my $TMPFILE = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $EXCLUDE = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
my $ROOT = "/";
my @devNum;

# Create an array of the file stats for "/"
my @rootStats = stat("${ROOT}");

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${MTAB}" or die "Cannot open ${MTAB}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
  }
}

close MT;

# Build an array of each mountpoint's device number for future comparison
foreach (@mounts) {
  my @stats = stat($_);
  push(@devNum, $stats[0]);
}

# Read in the list of excluded files and create a regex from them
my $regExcld = do {
  open XCLD, "<${EXCLUDE}" or die "Cannot open ${EXCLUDE}, $!\n";
  my @ignore = <XCLD>;
  chomp @ignore;
  local $" = '|';
  qr/@ignore/;

};

# Create a regex to compare file device numbers to.
my $devRegex = do {
  chomp @devNum;
  local $" = '|';
  qr/@devNum/;

};

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir("${DIR}" or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${DIR}, $!") unless (-d "${DIR}");

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${DIR}${TMPFILE}" or die "Cannot open ${DIR}${TMPFILE}, $!";

foreach (@mounts) {
  # The anonymous subroutine which is executed by File::Find
  find sub {
    # Is it in a basic directory, ...
    return if $File::Find::dir =~ /sys|proc|dev/;

    # ...a regular file, ...
    return unless -f;

    # ...local, ...
    my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);
    return unless $dirStats[0] =~ $devRegex;

    # ...and world writable?
    return unless (((stat)[2] & S_IWUSR) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWGRP) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWOTH));

    # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files unless it is
    # in the list if exclusions
    print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n") unless ($File::Find::name =~ $regExcld);

  }, $_;

}

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${TMPFILE} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${DIR}${TMPFILE}") {
  unlink "${DIR}${TMPFILE}";

} else {
  rename("${DIR}${TMPFILE}","${DIR}${PERMFILE}") or die "Cannot rename file ${DIR}${TMPFILE}, $!";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dev` field result from `stat()` tells you the device number the inode lives on. That can be used to distinguish different mount points, as they'll have a different device number from the one you started at.

Comment: When you say "started at" do you mean where I ran the script from?

Comment: After poking at my keyboard for a while and going down and then backtracking over unnecessary paths I believe I have what I need: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46611/perl-script-to-find-world-writable-files-in-local-directories-only. I'm accepting your solution not only because it's the only one ( ;) ), but because it was just what I needed (and all I asked for): a push in the right direction.